# content of pdf is compressed with wicked_pdf gem in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, wicked-pdf

While using /show.pdf?debug=1, its showing the exact html content with proper css and data. But when trying to download the original pdf its showing compressed content inside the pdf. Using twitter-bootstrap as css.

here is the layout

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
   <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application",media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "number_pages" %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  </head>
  <body onload='number_pages'>
    <div id="header">
      <%= wicked_pdf_image_tag 'entity-10.png' %>
    </div>

    <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the controller code

```
def show
 @user = Payment.new('splace')



respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    render pdf: "invoice", layout: 'pdf.html',
           no_pdf_compression:true,
           disposition:  "inline",
           dpi: 300,
           encoding: "UTF-8",
           show_as_html: params[:debug].present?,
           :margin => {:top => 0,
                       :bottom => 0,
                       :left => 0,
                       :right => 0}

  end
end
```

Comment: For the css tag just remove the media all and replace it with media screen, project , avoid media print .

Comment: i did it, but still the same issue. pdf rendering the css but its compressed. How to get full html view?